# How do I convert YYYYMMDD to ISO 8601 in PHP?

Tags: php, date

I’m trying to convert what’s provided as 20140109 (or YYYYMMDD) in the database to an ISO 8601 format in for our meta tags. It should be obvious, but maybe I haven’t had enough coffee.

Comment: Just use `substr()` and concatenation, what's the problem?

Comment: your database should get fixed so those dates are stored in native date-type fields.

Answer (score 3):

You can use PHP DateTime class to format the date to ISO-8601.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.iso8601

```
$date = new DateTime( ... );
$date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

And your database should be fixed to the right date-type format, like people already comented.